# How to make custom tab using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following html, i want to make simple tab using jquery

```
<td style="border-color: black; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;">
    <div id="cont-1-1">
        My first tab content
    </div>
    <div id="cont-2-1">
        My second tab content
    </div>
</td>
<td style="width: 30px">
    <div id="tab-box">
    <div style="height: 121px;"><img class="cont-1-1" src="/Images/Tab1.png" /></div>
    <div style="border-left: 1px solid Black;"><img class="cont-2-1" src="/Images/Tab2.png" /></div>
    <div style="border-left: 1px solid Black; height: 40px;"></div>
    </div>
</td>
</td>
```

Where `Tab1.Png` and `Tab2.Png` are my tab headers and `div id :cont-1-1 and 2-1` are tab content,
i don't want to use any jquery plug-in for this, just need something simple when i click on tab,,hide and show contents

This is what i am trying :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#tab-box').each(function () {
                    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                    // which tab is active and it's associated content
                    var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('img');

                    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                    $active = $(Find First Tab from div);
                    $active.addClass('active');
                    $content = $($active.attr('class'));

                    // Hide the remaining content
                    $links.not($active).each(function () {
                        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (with JavaScript/jQuery alone) is to wrap up your "tabs" in divs (or spans, etc.) then set all of their css display's to none (except the default first tab). Then on clicks, you hide/show as necessary.

It takes a little extra (just a couple of lines) to make it cross-browser compatible, but I've done this more than once.

This example assumes that an element with id pic1 is the "tab" that is being "clicked" and there are 3 other tabs (pic2, pic3, & pic4).  Depending on how you want your page setup (with arrows, or by clicking un-highlighted tabs that stick out, etc.) put these commands in each .click function that you need (respectively hiding and showing the necessary pages).

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("#pic1").click(function (){
    $("#pic1").prop("hidden", false);
    $("#pic2").prop("hidden", true);
    $("#pic3").prop("hidden", true);
    $("#pic4").prop("hidden", true);
    $("#pic1").css("display", "inline");  //if using div, use display block instead
    $("#pic1").css("display", "normal");
    $("#pic2").css("display", "none");
    $("#pic3").css("display", "none");
    $("#pic4").css("display", "none");
});
});
```

I'm not sure why you have to be so redundant (using both "hidden" and .css("display", none) and setting display to both normal and the natural display of the element) etc., but without using all the lines here, it either won't work in IE or it won't work in FireFox, or both.

Also, you might think that you could use display "initial" instead of the "inline" or "block" or whatever the default display is for the element being re-shown, but I could never get it to work that way, myself.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [**jQueryUI Tabs**](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

If you really know that what you are developing is unlikely to change in the future and will never be that complicated then it is fine to create tabs yourself.

Otherwise, why not use a rock solid library that provides the extensibility that you might need in the future.

Comment: this is what i do not want to use :(

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to do that? I accept it may be a valid one but just out of interest.